# Union columns and remove blanks

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have a table which appears like this (I've shortened it for example purposes)

```
no               no19             no68
3387034694344500        
3387452540705400        
3388486878919450                
                 3371522572594880   
                 3372232397709690   
                 3373608476884750   
                                  3382142940562320
                                  3382142940562320
                                  3383084144363070
```

so no, no19 and no68 are 3 different columns, but the data in column 'no19' starts in the next row after data in column 'no' ends.

As between these columns I have a lot more data, I would like to create a readable table. I have merged these columns into one, using this code:

```
 CREATE TABLE MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
(
TOKEN varchar(255)
)                           
INSERT INTO MULTICURRENCY_CHECK
(
TOKEN
)
SELECT no FROM book1
    UNION ALL
SELECT no19 FROM book1
    UNION ALL
SELECT no68 FROM book1
```

The problem is, the result I got looks like this:

```
TOKEN
3387034694344500        
3387452540705400        
3388486878919450


3371522572594880
3372232397709690    
3373608476884750


3382142940562320
3382142940562320
3383084144363070
```

So there are blank rows between in column TOKEN. I've tried to delete them, but it by simple delete command but it's not working (tried those two below):

```
delete from multicurrency_check where TOKEN = ' '
delete from multicurrency_check where TOKEN is NULL
```

Perhaps there is a different way I should deal with this table, maybe quicker? As the original table looks like these (just sample data)

```
no                   a      b      no19             c    d      no68
    3387034694344500 data1  data4   
    3387452540705400 data2  data5   
    3388486878919450 data3  data6           
                                  3371522572594880 data7 data10
                                  3372232397709690 data8 data11
                                  3373608476884750 data9 data12
                                                                3382142940562320
                                                                3382142940562320
                                                                3383084144363070
```

so what I would like to have in the end is table like this:

```
 | TOKEN | a | b | c | d
```

where token is a merge of no, no19 and no68, and then folowwing a,b,c,d columns with data matching appropriate id from TOKEN column (a,b,c,d can be null)

Comment: I did not understand about the second part of the question. However you can delete "empty" records by following query: DELETE FROM multicurrency_check where COALESCE(RTRIM(LTRIM(TOKEN)),'') = '';

Comment: for the given data can you fill the result table with the expected transformations?

Comment: Okay it is working with COALESCE (don't know much about transact-sql). I think I will manage with the rest, now is just a matter of joining tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete them in your UNION query like:

```
SELECT no FROM table WHERE no IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT no19 FROM table WHERE no19 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT no68 FROM table where no68 IS NOT NULL
```

You could also use COALESCE() instead of union since a column only contains data when the other's are null:

```
SELECT COALESCE(no, no19, no68) FROM table
```

Instead of putting these values in their own table, you could start with the above queries and build off of them. Say you want to also bring in A,B or C,D into the results:

```
SELECT COALESCE(no, no19, no68) as newno, COALESCE(a,c) as ac, COALESCE(b,d) as bd FROM table;
```

As to why your DELETE didn't work, perhaps those NULL's aren't NULL. Perhaps they hold a TAB character or 50 spaces? In which case @sidux's comment on your Q would do the trick. Trimming the field and looking where its value is `=''`.

Comment: Interesting thing, I used this code:  SELECT COALESCE(no, no19, no68, no93, no107) as 'Token', 
COALESCE(localdate, LocalDate13, LocalDate62, LocalDate87, LocalDate101) as 'Date'
FROM Book1          but it doesnt show me all the result, as some Token numbers are messed and have text strings so the better use is this piece of code suggested by @marcin wojdak   SELECT 
isnull(no,'')+isnull(no19,'')+isnull(no68,'')+isnull(no93,'')+isnull(no107,'') as 'Token',
isnull(localdate,'')+isnull(LocalDate13,'')+isnull(LocalDate62,'')+isnull(LocalDate87,'')+isnull(LocalDate101,'') as 'Date',
FROM book1

Comment: That's interesting. I suspect what's happening is that the '+' operator is forcing a `CAST(field AS NumberFormat)` so that it can do it's thing. So the '+', while probably slower from a CPU perspective, is doing both the job of `CAST` and `COALESCE` at once. If your data isn't big, then that is a solid solution.

Comment: It isn't big at the moment as I work on sample only, but the purpose is to apply it for a very large database. What do you suggest then?

Comment: I think the biggest performance issue you are going to have stems from the dirty data in your table. It seems like you have records that look NULL but actually have white space in them (tabs and spaces). That renders `COALESCE()` useless, so you then have to rely on more janky solutions like `isnull()+isnull()...` or `COALESCE(TRIM(field), TRIM(field2),...)` both of which will be expensive when your data grows. If performance is going to be an issue, then clean the data.

Comment: Clearing the data is not an option, because it is being sent externally and loaded to database. Actually what I need is just to work on a daily, weekly and monthly pieces. Do you think it will be quicker if I create a view first for appropriate period and then run my query?

Comment: It's tough to say. This is really one of those things where you'll have to experiment a bit. With SQL there is generally 3 or 4 ways to solve a problem, so sometimes you just have to pick at it and see what works best for you server, data, schema, and desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select
isnull(no,'')+isnull(no19,'')+isnull(no68,''),
a,b,c,d
from book1
```

That should concatenate all token in a row (and only one from no, no19 and no68 will have a value).

Comment: Cool, this is much quicker than UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

I created a table 'foo' with 3 text columns, like so:

```
       column1            column2            column3
       -------            -------            -------
row1   3371522572594880                      3373608476884750
row2   asdfasdf                              asdfasdf
row3                      3387452540705400   3388486878919450
```

Then executed the query

```
select token from(
select column1 as token from foo where column1 != '' 
union all 
select column2 as token from foo where column2 != ''
union all
select column3 as token from foo where column3 != ''
)
```

And got the result:

```
token
3371522572594880
asdfasdf
3387452540705400
3388486878919450
3373608476884750
asdfasdf
```

Is that what you're after?